# HTML: how can I remove this dotted line?

Tags: html, css

I'm using Drupal for a website, and I've a link "Unselect All" to deselect all items.

How can I remove the dotted line around "Unselect All" when I click on it ?????

Check this [link](http://www.sanstitre.ch/drupal/).

thanks

Comment: The focus marker is essential for people navigating without a pointing device (e.g. with the keyboard or a breath switch). Hiding it makes it impossible to track where the focus is. Throwing the focus away after selecting "Unselect All" means people have to work through the entire document to get back to that point. It is best just to leave it, people are used to seeing focus markers in documents they are interacting with.

Comment: Further to @David Dorward's comment, and the answer below, please consider an alternate means of visually indicating the ':focus', such as background-color or other border of some sort. The outline is not aesthetically pleasing, but its function **is** established.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
a.bef-toggle:link, a.bef-toggle:visited, a.bef-toggle:active {
    outline: none;
}
```

Please take heed of David's comments on the question though, this has accessibility side effects that you need to be aware of.

Comment: The focus marker will be reveled as soon as the mouse button is released (and the element is no longer `:active`)

Comment: Versions of IE prior to 8 do not support the `outline` property. Just something to be aware of.

Comment: Now you've edited it … the `:active` selector is redundant. You could get the same effect with `a.bef-toggle`

Answer (score 1):

I simply set `outline` to `none` for all and any link:

```
a {
 outline: none;
}
```

**Side Note:** This property does not work however in IE < 8.

Comment: How do you indicate `:focus` to users in the absence of an outline?

Comment: @ricebowl: I have set the style for links only and i don't indicate focus on links other than changing their styling to make them selected/focused.

Comment: You can't change their style to make them selected/focused. That is a state governed by the user interacting with the document. This code changes their style so the user cannot tell when they are focused (which is a user hostile thing to do and needs you to indicate the focus in some other way … which is what ricebowl was asking about).

Comment: @David Dorward: I did not mean selecting like what is done by the outline propery, what i meant was changing the color of the link based on a particular page i am on, for example.

Comment: That's a completely different issue. Knowing where the focus is tells you what happens if you press "Enter" (or equivalent) and suggests where you will go next when you press "Tab" (or equivalent).